# Adapt div size to the longest in a list

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using a material list in angular and each list item is composed of three fields :

- name of the item (**random size**)
- datepicker (**fixed size**)
- notes (**flexing to fill** the rest of the div)

  ```
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="company in companies" ng-click="null">
       <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
          <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
             <h3>{{ company.general_name }}</h3>
             <md-datepicker ng-model="whater" ng-change="patch()">
             </md-datepicker>
             <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Coms</label>
                <textarea ng-model="whatever"></textarea>
             </md-input-container>
          </div>
       </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
  ```

  I want the second field (datepicker) to start everytime at the same place which would be determined by the longest name. What I want is for the datepickers to be in a straight line so it looks "cleaner".

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/OxqmWN) and a drawing of what I want to achieve [image]

The easier way I found to do it is to use a fixed size for the name aswell using text-elipsis if there is an overflow, but I **don't** really want to use this solution unless I can't find a better way to do it.

Comment: Could you update the codepen link? It appears to be broken

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed !

Comment: Because the content is split into rows, I don't think there's a way to set `h3` to the width of the longest one using Flexbox. I think a `flex` or `width` value is needed. Alternatively, you could try `grid` layout, or even `table`?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. This is a temporary fix I need to deploy asap so I guess I'll use flex and text-ellipsis :)

Comment: Have you considered using a table?  That might be the quickest fix.  Otherwise, you could have a JS function that measures the widest name-field and sets the width of the rest to match.